# Convert escaped string to bytearray or stream; c#

Tags: c#, unicode, stream, arrays

My input string consists of a mixture of unicode escape characters with regular characters mixed in. Example:

```
\u0000\u0003\u0000\u0013timestamp\u0011clientId\u0015timeToLive\u0017destination\u000fheaders\tbody\u0013messageId\u0001\u0006
```

How can I convert this into a bytearray or Stream?

EDIT: UTF+8 encoding. To clarify the input string:

```
Char 01: U+0000
Char 02: U+0003
Char 03: U+0000
Char 04: U+0013
Char 05: t
Char 06: i
Char 07: m
Char 08: e
Char 09: s
Char 10: t
Char 11: a
Char 12: m
Char 13: p
Char 14: U+0011
...
...
```

Comment: Please give more context. For example, is the first character in your string actually the Unicode U+0000 character, or is it a backslash? And what encoding do you want to use in the stream or byte array?

Comment: Seems you are trying to read a binary file as text.

Comment: There is a good example in the 'Example' section of the [Encoding.Unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx) page

Comment: @I4V The original data is indeed a binary stream. A program I don't control spits it out to a log in this form. I want to convert it back to a stream so I can use it.

Comment: @RaGe then post a sample binary data, It is hard to say anything without it.

Comment: edited to add expected byte array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so you've got an arbitrary string (the fact that it contains non-printable characters is irrelevant) and you want to convert it into a byte array using UTF-8. That's easy :)

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

Or to write to a stream, you'd normally wrap it in a `StreamWriter`:

```
// Note that due to the using statement, this will close the stream at the end
// of the block
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(text);
}
```

(UTF-8 is the default encoding for `StreamWriter`, but you can specify it explicitly of course.)

I'm assuming you really have a good reason to have "text" in this form though. I can't say I've ever found a use for U+0003 (END OF TEXT). If, as I4V has suggested, this data was originally in a binary stream, you should avoid handling it as text in the first place. Separate out your binary data from your text data - when you mix them, it *will* cause issues. (For example, if the fourth character in your string were U+00FF, it would end up as two bytes when encoded to UTF-8, which probably wouldn't be what you wanted.)

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the conversion just do this:

```
var stream = new memoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
```

Or if you want a approach that  have concerns about  reusability, create a [Extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/bb383977.aspx) to strings like this:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
     public static Stream ToStream(this string str)
       =>new memoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str))         

     //Or much better
     public static Stream ToStreamWithEncoding(this string str, Encoding encoding)
       =>new memoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(str))
}
```